# Losing Input Focus when Typing in Input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to make a questionnaire with a question box, 2 option boxes at the beginning, and an 'add option +' button to append more options for each question. While typing in the question box works fine, typing in the option box causes the focus to be lost after typing any character. To clarify, after typing a single character, the focus shifts away. This means that in order to input any characters, I need to click the option input box again to regain focus.

States:

```
const [qno, setQno] = useState(0);
  const initialMCQ = {
    id: qno,
    type: 'Multiple Choice',
    question: '',
    options: ['', ''],
  };
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([initialMCQ]);
```

Logics:

```
  const onChangeQuestionMCQ = (e, questionIndex) => {
    const updatedQuestions = [...questions];
    updatedQuestions[questionIndex].question = e.target.value;
    setQuestions(updatedQuestions);
  };

  const onChangeOptionMCQ = (e, questionIndex, optionIndex) => {
    const updatedQuestions = [...questions];
    const temp = e.target.value;
    updatedQuestions[questionIndex].options[optionIndex] = temp;
    setQuestions(updatedQuestions);
  };
```

Code:

```
{questions.map((que, questionIndex) => (
  <Grid item className={classes.questionBox} key={que.id}>
    <input
      placeholder="Write question here"
      className={classes.questionInputField}
      onChange={(e) => onChangeQuestionMCQ(e, questionIndex)}
      value={que.question}
    />

    <ul className={classes.optionsList}>
      {que.options.map((opt, optionIndex) => (
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        <li className={classes.optionListItem} key={`${opt}-${optionIndex}`}>
          <label htmlFor={`option_${questionIndex}_${optionIndex}`} className={classes.openListItemLable}>
            <input type="radio" id={`option_${questionIndex}_${optionIndex}`} />
            <input
              className={classes.optionText}
              onChange={(e) => onChangeOptionMCQ(e, questionIndex, optionIndex)}
              placeholder="Option"
              value={opt}
            />
          </label>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
    <Button className={classes.addOption} onClick={() => handleAddOption(questionIndex)}>
      + Add option
    </Button>
  </Grid>
))}
```

I tried material-ui TextField but that also did not work.

could you guys help me resolving this?

Comment: Most likely you declared one component inside another, but you didn't show enough code to know for sure

Comment: @Konrad This is the entire code for this component. I guess the issue was with its key. I tried with a UUID, and it's working now.

Comment: Could you create a minimal example on codesandbox?

Comment: @Konrad sure I will update here after a couple of hours